# Execute function after finishes a Filestack process

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filestack

I'm using Filestack v3, I want to compare words number of DOC/DOCX files with number of pages. With the premise: "Each page has 200 words" I want to formulate that, for example: "If a doc/docx file has 2 pages, in theory, that file has 400 words, if it has 400 or more than 400 words is OK, otherwise is WRONG".

So, I have this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="files">UPLOAD</button>
<textarea id="dkd"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="text" id="cnw">
<input type="text" id="cnp">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.filestackapi.com/v3/filestack.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JS code is:

```
$("#files").click(function(){
  var client = filestack.init('myAPI');

  client.pick({
    accept: ['image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif','application/pdf','application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'],
    fromSources: ['local_file_system','googledrive','gmail','facebook','dropbox','onedrive','webcam'],
    lang: 'es',     
    maxSize: 2097152,
    maxFiles: 100
  }).then(function(Blobs) {

  var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Blobs));

  for(var i=0; i<result.filesUploaded.length; i++){

    if(result.filesUploaded[i].mimetype=="application/msword" || result.filesUploaded[i].mimetype=="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"){

        var dataFile = "https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/output=docinfo:true/"+result.filesUploaded[i].handle;
        var handlee = result.filesUploaded[i].handle;
        var lcconvert = "https://process.filestackapi.com/output=format:txt/"+result.filesUploaded[i].handle;

        //GET NUMBER OF WORDS
        $("#dkd").load(lcconvert, function(){               
            $.post("load2.php",{
                url: $("#dkd").val()
            }).success(function(response){

                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='mswcount' value='"+response+"'>";
                var arr = document.getElementsByName('mswcount');
                var tot=0;
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);

                }                       

                document.getElementById('cnw').value = tot;

            });
        });

        //GET NUMBER OF PAGES
        $.post("numpage.php",{
            dF: dataFile
        }).success(function(response){

            var numpages = $.trim(response);// number of pages
            $("#cnp").val(numpages);

        });//post
    }//if
  }//for

  inspire();

 });//client.pick
});//files


//COMPARISON
function inspire(){

   var pag = $("#cnp").val();//pages
   var pagpal = pag*200; //number of pages * 200 = number of words
   var pal = $("#cnw").val();//words

   console.log("Pages: "+pag);
   console.log("Words: "+pal);

   if(pal>=pagpal){
      console.log("OK");
   } else {
      console.log("WRONG");
   }
}
```

I want function called **inspire** do the comparison with input values and show the result in console (number of pages, number of words and final message), but the problem is **inspire** function executes before Filestack process finishes and I want Filestack process finishes first putting values on inputs and then function executes.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that you want to run in the `client.pick(/**/).then()` callback. Or use `await`/`async` to wait for `client.pick` to return a value: https://javascript.info/async-await